# TCP connection to send and receive Java/Android with Visual Basic .NET Server

Tags: java, android, vb.net, tcp

I have searched everywhere to find an answer for this question:

I have a TCP client on my android application that sends an message to the server which is written in Visual Basic .NET Framework 4.

Now i want to send an message from my server to the phone over 3g, it works on wifi and 3g..

```
 private class startserver extends Thread
{
public void server() throws Exception
{
   String clientSentence;
   String capitalizedSentence;
   ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8765);

   while(true)
   {
      Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
      BufferedReader inFromClient =
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
      DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
      clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
      System.out.println(clientSentence.substring(1));
      msgshower = clientSentence.substring(1);
      MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Received: " + msgshower , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
      });
      capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
      outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
   }
}


@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        server();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I start it in the OnCreate method

Now i send a message with (VB.NET)

```
Private Sub sends(ByVal message As String)
    Dim tcp As New TcpClient
    tcp.Connect(connectedIP, 8765)
    Dim bw As New IO.BinaryWriter(tcp.GetStream)
    bw.Write(message)
    bw.Close()
    tcp.Close()
End Sub
```

On wifi it will arrive, on 3g it wont... any idea's how to do this?

How do other applications archive this?

Comment: How do you get the IP address to connect to from VB?

Comment: the ip that was connected,

`        Dim listener As TcpListener = CType(ar.AsyncState, TcpListener)
        Dim clientSocket As TcpClient = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)
        Dim Data

        Dim rcvData As New IO.StreamReader(clientSocket.GetStream)
        Data = rcvData.ReadLine

        connectedIP = clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString.Split(":")(0)
        rcvData.Close()
        clientSocket.Close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're having problem with the ip address asigned by your mobile phone operator. The fact that works on wifi, but not on 3G, I think that is because your mobile(when connected through 3G) doesn't have a public IP address.

When you use SocketServer in your mobile, you're opening a port a waiting for others to connect to it. If your IP address is not reachable from internet, it won't happen (it's like having a computer behind a firewall.)

Could you try to implement the server in the VB machine, assuming that it has a public reachable address? This way, the phone wouldn't act as a server, it wouldn't be necessary to have a reachable address, as long as the VB machine has one. Then, you should use Socket class to bind to the server ip and port.

Comment: You can have bidirectional communication once your connection is established using getInputStream() and getOutputStream() in your socket object. But I'm sorry. If you don't have a public address in your mobile, the connection cannot be started by the server. That's the reason FTP protocol implemented passive mode. However, depending on the context you want to deploy your app, public addresses are usually able to be purchased. It depends on your telecom.

Answer (score 0):

Totally confused by your code list above..

If you want to host a server in VB.NET, you should **not** use `TcpClient` class but `TcpListener` and if you need a better performance, use `Socket` class directly.

At the Android client side, you should `new Socket(server,servPort)`, when you want to send message, write the `outputStream`, and read the `inputStream` to receive message.